# how to find list of all the objects referred in a stored procedure in AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

How do I get list of all the objects that are being referenced in a stored procedure in AWS redshift?

Comment: I don't think there is any magical shortcut. You'll have to analyze the Stored Procedure yourself.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. We are looking for a automated way to get this information rather than looking for it in every SP.